# MySqlException (0x80004005): : Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, azure

Hello I'm having troubles connecting to my database, via my website. 
When i open a page, which tries to acces my database i get an error page saying 
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'UserName'@'IP' (using password: YES)]

I am useing a azure server and database, and is trying to connect using my admin user. 
This is the connection string am useing

```
Database={DatabaseName}; Data Source=ServerName.mysql.database.azure.com; User
 Id=UserName@ServerName; Password={UserPassword}
```

The user is set to Host = % 
and should have all of the necesary administrative roles.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the braces around database and password, and it worked. 
Can't even remeber why i had put them there.